# Css Selector From Class Name in selenium

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Im trying to get Css selector for this class(below HTML Code) like

```
1)input[class='js-AddNuts'][type='button'] Selector: CSS
2)input[class='btn js-AddNuts'][type='button']
3)input[class='btn js-AddNuts']
```

It fails to locate this element

Html Code

```
<button class="btn js-AddNuts" data-nuts-single-id="1" data-nuts-target-id="SectionIa_AddressContractingBody_Nuts_NutsString" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Why are you going for `cssSelector`. if you can simply find the element `By.id("SectionIa_AddressContractingBody_Nuts_NutsString")`???

Comment: this ID is not selenium ID, it was not working. Devs Said thats some data attribute ID

Comment: ah my mistake...Corrected your question..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `button` element, not `input`. Use the *dot notation* to check a class value:

```
button.btn.js-AddNuts
button.js-AddNuts
button[class*=AddNuts]
```